# Issue in iPhone Dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdictionary

I am revolving around with a small issue in iPhone while playing around Array and Dictionary. I have and product dictionary with the following data

```
  name = Product;
    options =     (
                {
            code = code1;
            name = "product AAA";
        },
                {
            code = code1;
            name = "product BBB";
        },
                {
            code = "code2";
            name = "product BBB";
        },
                {
            code = "code3";
            name = "product CCC";
        },
                {
            code = "code3";
            name = "product DDD";
        },
                {
            code = code4;
            name = "product EEE";
        },
                {
            code = code4;
            name = "product FFF";
        }
    );
```

Also i have an array of matching products

```
matchingProducts
{
    "product BBB",
    "product CCC",
    "product DDD"
)
```

Now, all i want to do is i want to remove from products dictionary comparing to matchingProducts array.  how can i do it. 
Note: I cannot use key to remove objects as per my business rules. I have issue as i have names are repeated but i have to get the final result dictionary as shown below. Is it possible.

```
   name = Product;
    options =     (
                {
            code = code1;
            name = "product AAA";
        },
                {
            code = code1;
            name = "product BBB";
        },
                {
            code = code4;
            name = "product EEE";
        },
                {
            code = code4;
            name = "product FFF";
        }
    );
```

Please, reply me back if my question is not clear.

I have fixed the similar issue in java using the below code

```
for (int j = 0; j < matchingProducts.size(); j++) {
 String product = ((Product) matchingProducts.elementAt(i)).name;

 for (int i = 0; i <Product.size(); i++) {
     String productName = ((Product) Product.elementAt(i)).name;
     if (product.equals(productName)) {
  Product.removeElementAt(i);
  break;
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: i have used an array to extract the dictionary value and trying to achieve it .. but failed

Comment: If you are unable to use the key (which i assume is the product code in this scenario), what would be the rule you use to match and remove similar objects? e.g. how would you decide between removing 'code 1, product BBB' and 'code 2, product BBB'

Comment: @Neel, I see 2 arrays. Which one is dictionary and what are its keys?

Comment: @Madhumal I have placed the java code. I am well versed in java. I am looping the matchingProducts array and getting the element using loop counter as index. Now checking that with the each element of the products dictionary. if matching then removing the dictionary object according to the index. then i am using break. please suggest any such logic will work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *Product = initialize like you did with Products;
NSMutableDictionary *resultant = [NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; //this will have your result    
NSArray *keys = [Product allKeys];
for(int i = 0 ; i < [keys count]; i++)
  {
    id temp = [Product objectForKey:keys[i]];

 bool matchFound = NO;
for (int j = 0; j < [matchingProduct count]; j++)
   {
     id temptemp = [matchingProduct objectAtIndex:j] //Assuming matchingProduct is an NSArray or NSMutableArray
     if(temp == temptemp)
       {
           matchFound = YES;
       }
   }

  if(!matchFound)
     [resultant addObject:temp];
```

}

// resultant now has what you wanted. Use it.

Comment: from my above product dictionary,how can i access the all codes names along with values from dictionary.It internally holds the options array.

Comment: Can you post your declaration for both Product dictionary and matchingProduts array ?

Comment: NSDictionary *productDict = nil;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in items) 
    {
     if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Product"]) 
     {
      productDict = dict;
      break;
     } }
 
 NSArray *matchingProducts;
     for(int i=0;i<[selectedStateDictvalues  count];i++)
     {   
     NSString *optionString = (NSString*)[selectedStateDictKeys objectAtIndex:i];
      if([optionString isEqualToString:@"ExcludeProduct"])
       {  
        matchingProducts =[[[[selectedStateDictvalues objectAtIndex:i]  objectForKey:@"options"] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.name"] retain];
}}

Comment: hey neel it would be better if you move this to gmail or something. I am sure I can help you with this. If you are interested mail me the relevant code for the all the declarations : productDict, Items, MatchingProducts etc and I will send you the solution. If you do it now, expect an answer by tonight. sayeedhussain19@gmail.com